# SolrException: HTTP code=404, reason=Not Found WARNI [ckan.lib.search] Problems were found while connecting to the SOLR server

Tags: solr, ckan

I was new to CKAN m finding error while running CKAN m using ckan 2.3 with solr 5.0.0 , please help me solve this error:

```
SolrException: HTTP code=404, reason=Not Found
2015-06-24 10:28:59,194 WARNI [ckan.lib.search] Problems were found while connecting to the SOLR server
2015-06-24 10:29:01,040 ERROR [ckan.lib.search.common] HTTP code=404, reason=Not Found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/search/common.py", line 51, in is_available
    conn.query("*:*", rows=1)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 703, in query
    return self.select(*args, **params)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 798, in __call__
    xml = self.raw(**params)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 823, in raw
    rsp = conn._post(self.selector, request, conn.form_headers)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 639, in _post
    return check_response_status(self.conn.getresponse())
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/solr/core.py", line 1097, in check_response_status
    raise ex
SolrException: HTTP code=404, reason=Not Found
2015-06-24 10:29:01,041 WARNI [ckan.lib.search] Problems were found while connecting to the SOLR server
```

Comment: Is your solr instance running?

Comment: yes solr is running in localhost:8983/solr... followed steps in http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html#setting-up-solr   but it didn't worked. so installed  solr 5.0.0 manually.